# Magento and country codes for table rates

Tags: magento

Where can I find a list of all country codes for Magento, in order to configure the tables rates file for shipment to all countries globally?

Comment: http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/magento-country-codes-for-table-rate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the answers lie in the following file found in the magento folder:

lib/Zend/Locale/Data/supplementalData.xml

Some deduction might be necessary.  But do a search for "USA" to get to the relevant section. In my file, it was on line 4590 and from there you deduce the other country codes.

Comment: two-letter codes can be found here:
http://www.theodora.com/country_digraphs.html
to help deduce the 3-letter codes Magento uses in the above file.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.7, if you need to get it from code:

```
$countries = Mage::helper('directory')->getCountryCollection();
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    echo $country->getIso2_code();
}
```

If you need 3 letter code replace getIso2_code() with getIso3_code().

Comment: The above code will output countries configured for the store in use. If you need the whole list you should access directly the country collection: `$countries = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getResourceCollection();`